# How to deal with non UTF-8 encoded urls in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, url-encoding, bing

We have a node js application which we have recently moved over from running on IIS 7 (via IIS node) to running on Linux (Elastic Beanstalk). Since we switched, we've been getting a lot of non UTF-8 urls being sent to our application (mainly from crawlers) such as:

`Bj%F6rk` which IIS was converting to `Björk`. This is now being passed to our application and our web framework (express) eventually calls down to

`decodeURIComponent('Bj%F6rk');
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (native)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:532:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:761:14)`

Is there a recommended safe way we can perform the same conversion as IIS before sending the url string to express?

Bearing in mind

1. We are receiving requests to these badly encoded URLS and
2. There is a way to decode them using the [deprecated `unescape` javascript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) and
3. The majority of the requests to these URLs are coming from Bing Bot and we want to minimise any adverse effect on our search rankings.

   - Should we really be doing this for all incoming URLs?
   - Are there any security or performance implications we should be concerned about?
   - Should we be concerned about `unescape` being removed in the near future?
   - Is there a better / safer way to solve this problem (Yes we did read that MDN article linked to above)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should we really be doing this for all incoming URLs?

No, you shouldn't. The request being made uses non-UTF8 URI components. That shouldn't be your problem.

> Are there any security or performance implications we should be
>   concerned about?

The encoding of a URI component is not a security issue. Injection attempts via querystring or path params are. But that's another subject. In terms of performance, every middleware will make your responses take a bit longer. But I wouldn't even worry about that. If you want to decode the URI yourself, just do it. It'll only take a few milliseconds.

> Should we be concerned about unescape being removed in the near
>   future?

Actually you should. `unescape` is deprecated. If you still want to use it; just check if it exists first. i.e. `'unescape' in global`. You can also use the built-in alternate: `require('querystring').unescape()` which won't produce the same result in every case but it won't throw a `URIError`. (Not recommended though).

**To minimise any adverse effect on search rankings:**

Determine which status code your express app returns in these cases. It could be **500** (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) which will look bad and **404** (NOT FOUND) which will tell the crawler you don't have a result for the query (which may not be true).

In these cases, I suggest you override this by returning a client error such as **400** (BAD REQUEST) instead, since the origin of the problem is a malformed URI component being requested, which should be in UTF-8 but it's not. The crawler/bot should be concerned about that.

```js
// middleware for responding with BAD REQUEST
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err instanceof URIError) {
        res.status(400).send();
    }
});
```

Above all, trying to return a result for a malformed URI has other side effects. First, you'll be allowing a bad request — can't be good :). Secondly, it'll mean you have a result for a bad URI which will get stored by crawlers/bots when they get a 200 OK response and it will get spread. Then you'll have to deal with more bad requests.

**To conclude**; don't decode via `unescape`. Express already tries to decode via what's proper: `decodeURIComponent`. If that fails, let it be.

Comment: This is matches what we'd come to think and is what we'll be rolling forward with.   Thanks for the detailed answers to the questions.  Enjoy your bounty, don't eat it all at once! :)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js [`queryString`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_unescape) library has safe implementation of `escape` and `unescape` methods. They both uses utf-8 encoding. `unescape` first tries `decodeURIComponent` and when fails it tries with a [safe fast alternative implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2a7fd0ad328d5197a9a166650e9eaa51367e3152/lib/querystring.js#L15).

```
> querystring.escape('ö')
'%C3%B6'
> querystring.unescape('%C3%B6')
'ö'
```

But you have [latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96#Codes_for_computing) encoded string (`%F6` instead of `%C3%B6` ), so `querystring.unescape` would give unexpected result, but it wouldn't break your code:

```
> querystring.unescape('Bj%F6rk')
'Bj�rk'
```

You might be able to convert from latin1 to utf-8 and get the right string using `iconv` or `iconv-lite` package. But [URL encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) should be in UTF-8.  So I think it's safe to ignore other encoded strings and just use `querystring.unescape`.

---

In express 4.7.x, you can set [`query parser`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.settings.table) configuration to `simple` to use `querystring.parse` which internally uses `querystring.unescape`.

```
app.set('query parser', 'simple') // or 'extended' to use 'qs' module
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Nodejs decode-uri-charset, https://www.npmjs.com/package/decode-uri-charset

```
var url_decode = require('decode-uri-charset');
console.log(url_decode('%C7%CF%C0%CC', 'euc-kr'))
```